# How to split each item in an string-array xml list and add it to a new arraylist?

Tags: java, android, arrays

My activity has a listview that prints out every item from the string array, but what I am trying to do is only show the first part of the string and the second part is needed for the next activity. When the activity loads it shows part1|part2. I can't get it working for the first load of the activity, but for the OnItemClickListener it works to split the string and send part2 to another activity.

```
<string-array name="test">
    <item>Dummy1|test1 test2 test3</item>
    <item>Dummy2|test4</item>
    <item>Dummy3|test5</item>
</string-array>
```

I am using a delimiter " | " to split the string.

```
String title, sub_category, part1, part2;
Bundle bundle;
String[] sub_category_list, seperated;
ListView listView;
Object sub_cat_name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.subcategory_layout);

    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    title = bundle.getString("selected_category");

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    sub_category_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test);

    (Print out only the first part of each item. 
    I need a function here that splits each strings)

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sub_category_list);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_single, R.id.txt, sub_category_list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            sub_cat_name = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            seperated = sub_cat_name.toString().split("\\|");
            part1 = seperated[0];
            part2 = seperated[1];
            sub_category = sub_cat_name.toString();


            Toast.makeText(SubCategory.this, "You clicked at : " + (part2) + (position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried using a for loop to add all the first parts to a new ArrayList.

```
public ArrayList<String> newList;

    sub_category_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.popular);
    for (String i : sub_category_list){
        String[] split1 = i.split("\\|");
        String abc = split1[0];
        String def = split1[1];
        newList.add(abc);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,  R.layout.list_single, R.id.txt, newList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: what is the exact issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Map<String,String> partsMap = new HashMap<>();

private ArrayList<String> getFisrtPartString() {
    ArrayList<String> firstPartStringsList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test)));

    String firstPart;
    String secondPart;

    for(String stringInStringArray : new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test)))) {
        firstPart = stringInStringArray.split("|")[0];
        secondPart = stringInStringArray.split("|")[1];
        partsMap.put(firstPart, secondPart);
    }
    firstPartStringsList.addAll(partsMap.keySet());
    return firstPartStringsList;
}
```

It will initialize a map that get the first part of the String as key and the second part as value, and return a list (so you can use it for your ListView/RecyclerView adapter) of "first part of the strings".
Regarding the second phase, which needs the second part of the string, it's up to you to use the map's values (that contains at this stage the second part of the strings) and to deliver it to whoever need it.